# React frontend and nodejs microservices in docker Containers, how to implement Google OAuth2.0

Tags: reactjs, docker, networking, oauth-2.0, microservices

I cannot find a way to make the react container and a microservice container communicate with google OAuth2.0

I have build a set of microservices in nodejs and a frontend in React. In react app i have wrapped the entire app in:

```
<GoogleOAuthProvider clientId='<client-id>'>
            <div className="App">
                ...
            </div>
        </GoogleOAuthProvider>
```

I have implemented google OAuth2.0 so that when the users clicks in google login and the login is succefull success() is called with the credential that google responded with.

```
return (
        <GoogleLogin
            onSuccess={credentialResponse => {
                success(credentialResponse);
            }}
            onError={(error) => {
                failure(error);
            }}
        />
    );
};

export default GoogleLoginButton;
```

Then the function success() sends this google credential to a backend microservice where it gets verified with this function;

```
const client = new OAuth2Client(process.env.CLIENT_ID);
```

Then, the information is extracted and i have implemented access token refresh token interface. Lastly, access token and refresh token are sent back in the frontend. These are used to authenticate users accross the other microservices.

My problem is that i must dockerize all the microservices and the react app. When i do that i cannot access google OAuth from with the auth microservice and the react app. Is there any way to solve this problem? If not what is the easiest way to implement google log in with dockerized microservices.

This is an assignment for my university.
Τhank you in advance

Comment: You need to add some details of what exactly is failing in dockerized context - it should work if it's working outside. Other than that, a popular way is to use keycloak for OAuth and node js adapter - https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_nodejs_adapter